# When does class_implements returns false?

Tags: php

I've gone through the documentation about this function but i can't seem to find a way to get that function to return false. Documentation says the return type is array|false

```
class_implements('NonExistingClass');
// Warning: class_implements(): Class \NonExistingClass does not exist and could not be loaded
class_implements('\StdClass')
// returns empty array
```

When does it returns false and not raise warning?

Comment: You get a warning but it [still returns false](https://3v4l.org/kgTj3)

Comment: use class_exists first, class_implements returns what a known class implements, its job is not to check if the class_exists..

Comment: You could also use `@` to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a nonexistent class to the `class_implements()` function, it returns `False` as well as generates a warning. As @Barmar suggested you can add `@` in front of the function to suppress the warning.

`@class_implements('NonExistingClass')`

This will return false and won't generate a warning.